# Meaning of 200 response/no errors from dry_run request

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

[dry_run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) can be set so that pushes aren't sent, but that tokens can be  validated by FCM.

If the response to a dry_run is 200 and there are no [errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes), does that guarantee that if dry_run was not set that there is a an app installation on a device that FCM could target with that message.

The only scenario I can think of is if there is a delay:

1. dry run enabled in request
2. user uninstalls the app (or some other event which invalidates the token)
3. FCM returns 200/no error
4. FCM receives data relayed from the device that the app was uninstalled and token is invalid

Are there other scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the FCM token by calling the

```
(GET) https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/YOUR_APP_TOKEN_HERE
[Header] => 'Authorization: key=YOUR_KEY'
```

Simple and easy.

If token is valid then it will return 200 status code with some more details in JSON format or if it's invalid then status code will be 400 with error detail in JSON format.

Implement this code server side. get token from database (if you are saving token in database) and passin the above URL and it will send you token status whether if it expired or not.